# Nyctanthes arbor-tristis tree branch breaking by itself

Tags: trees, flowering

Of late i started observing that several branches of the so called coral jasmine tree were broken and hanging. Certainly there was a spell of gusty winds blowing through. Is there any known disease that has affected these trees, or the tree branches are weaker by nature.

Comment: Would you please post a few pictures, including the whole tree and a close up of where the breaking branches meet the trunk? That would be very helpful. Also, where do you live? How old is the tree? How tall is it? Thanks!